# Can I replace Nans with the mode of a column in a grouped data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, imputation

I have some data that looks like...

```
Year      Make   Model  Trim
2007     Acura  TL      Base
2010     Dodge  Avenger SXT
2009     Dodge  Caliber SXT
2008     Dodge  Caliber SXT
2008     Dodge  Avenger SXT
```

`Trim` has some missing values. What I would like to do is something like the following:

- Group by year make and model
- Impute Trim if there are missing valyes for that group

So for instance, I would look at all the 2007 Acura TL.  That might look like

```
 Year      Make   Model Trim
2007     Acura  TL      Base
2007     Acura  TL      XLR
2007     Acura  TL      NaN
2007     Acura  TL      Base
```

Then, I would impute the Nan with Base (since Base is the Mode).  It is important to remember here that I want to do this for every group of Year, Make, and Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` then `mode`.  Note that `mode` returns an array and you want to grab the first element of it.  @John Galt deserves credit for this and gets my upvote.

I use `assign` to create a copy of `df` with an overwritten version of the `Trim` column.

```
df.assign(
    Trim=df.groupby(
        ['Year', 'Make', 'Model']
    ).Trim.apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])
    )
)

   Year   Make Model  Trim
0  2007  Acura    TL  Base
1  2007  Acura    TL   XLR
2  2007  Acura    TL  Base
3  2007  Acura    TL  Base
```

---

You can overwrite the column directly with

```
df['Trim'] = df.groupby(
    ['Year', 'Make', 'Model']
).Trim.apply(
    lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know about assign, that looks handy

Comment: Thanks for the tip about mode returning an array and to grab the first element. I was stuck on this for a while because I didn't include the [0].

Answer (score 4):

Use mode

```
In [215]: df
Out[215]:
   Year   Make    Model  Trim
0  2007  Acura       TL  Base
1  2010  Dodge  Avenger   SXT
2  2009  Dodge  Caliber   NaN
3  2008  Dodge  Caliber   SXT
4  2008  Dodge  Avenger   SXT

In [216]: df.Trim.fillna(df.Trim.mode()[0])
Out[216]:
0    Base
1     SXT
2     SXT
3     SXT
4     SXT
Name: Trim, dtype: object
```

Use `inplace=True` to actually set

```
In [217]: df.Trim.fillna(df.Trim.mode()[0], inplace=True)

In [218]: df
Out[218]:
   Year   Make    Model  Trim
0  2007  Acura       TL  Base
1  2010  Dodge  Avenger   SXT
2  2009  Dodge  Caliber   SXT
3  2008  Dodge  Caliber   SXT
4  2008  Dodge  Avenger   SXT
```

---

If you're working on groups

```
In [227]: df
Out[227]:
   Year   Make Model  Trim
0  2007  Acura    TL  Base
1  2007  Acura    TL   XLR
2  2007  Acura    TL   NaN
3  2007  Acura    TL  Base

In [228]: (df.groupby(['Year', 'Make', 'Model'])['Trim']
             .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])))
     ...:
Out[228]:
0    Base
1     XLR
2    Base
3    Base
Name: Trim, dtype: object
```