# How to replace missing values with group mode in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, imputation

I follow the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741879/can-i-replace-nans-with-the-mode-of-a-column-in-a-grouped-data-frame) to replace missing values with the group mode, but encounter the "IndexError: index out of bounds".

```
 df['SIC'] = df.groupby('CIK').SIC.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
```

I guess this is probably because some groups have all missing values and do not have a mode. Is there a way to get around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mode` is quite difficult, given that there really isn't any agreed upon way to deal with ties. Plus it's typically very slow. Here's one way that will be "fast". We'll define a function that calculates the mode for each group, then we can fill the missing values afterwards with a `map`. We don't run into issues with missing groups, though for ties we arbitrarily choose the modal value that comes first when sorted:

```
def fast_mode(df, key_cols, value_col):
    """ 
    Calculate a column mode, by group, ignoring null values. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        DataFrame over which to calcualate the mode. 
    key_cols : list of str
        Columns to groupby for calculation of mode.
    value_col : str
        Column for which to calculate the mode. 

    Return
    ------ 
    pandas.DataFrame
        One row for the mode of value_col per key_cols group. If ties, 
        returns the one which is sorted first. 
    """
    return (df.groupby(key_cols + [value_col]).size() 
              .to_frame('counts').reset_index() 
              .sort_values('counts', ascending=False) 
              .drop_duplicates(subset=key_cols)).drop(columns='counts')
```

#### Sample data `df`:

```
   CIK  SIK
0    C  2.0
1    C  1.0
2    B  NaN
3    B  3.0
4    A  NaN
5    A  3.0
6    C  NaN
7    B  NaN
8    C  1.0
9    A  2.0
10   D  NaN
11   D  NaN
12   D  NaN
```

#### Code:

```
df.loc[df.SIK.isnull(), 'SIK'] = df.CIK.map(fast_mode(df, ['CIK'], 'SIK').set_index('CIK').SIK)
```

#### Output `df`:

```
   CIK  SIK
0    C  2.0
1    C  1.0
2    B  3.0
3    B  3.0
4    A  2.0
5    A  3.0
6    C  1.0
7    B  3.0
8    C  1.0
9    A  2.0
10   D  NaN
11   D  NaN
12   D  NaN
```