# How do I correctly impute these NaN values with modes of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, missing-data, imputation

I am learning how to handle missing values in a dataset. I have a table with ~1million entries. I'm trying to deal with a small number of missing values.

My data concerns a bicycle-share system and my missing values are start & end locations.

Data: missing starting stations, only 7 values

[image]

Data: missing ending station, 24 values altogether

[image]

I want to fill the `NaN` in both cases with the mode of the "opposite" station. Example, for `start_station==21`, I want to see what is the most common `end_station`, and use that to fill in my missing value.
E.g. `df.loc[df['start_station'] == 21].end_station.mode()`

I tried to achieve this with a function:

```py
def inpute_end_station(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():    
        if pd.isnull(df.loc[index, 'end_station']):

            start_st = df.loc[index, 'start_station']
            mode = df.loc[df['start_station'] == start_st].end_station.mode()
            df.loc[index, 'end_station'].fillna(mode, inplace=True)
```

The last line throws a `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'`. If instead I just use `df.loc[index, 'end_station'] = mode` I get `ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series`.

Am I approaching this properly? I understand it's bad practice to modify something you're iterating over in pandas so what's the correct way of changing `start_station` and `end_station` columns and replacing the `NaN`s with the corresponding mode of the complimentary station?

Comment: Seems similar to this question asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562696/how-to-replace-missing-values-with-group-mode-in-pandas. Should be able to use that same function (just with different column names), then map the result.

Comment: @ALollz the solution there does work with the helper function but I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`. Is this really the best way?

Comment: That error is likely unrelated to this, and stems from a prior slicing operation that generated a copy. You can read this for some more background in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas, but the TLDR band-aid fix is that you should probably just do `df = df.copy()` prior to whichever line of code threw that warning. In reality, you should fix the slice operation somewhere else, which probably requires a `.copy()` after some masking step, or to re-write code without chained assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, when you want to iterate over a column in pandas like this, the best practice is using `apply()` function.

For this particular case, I would suggest the following approach, that is shown below on my sample data. I do not have much experience using `mode()` method, so I used `value_counts()` method in combination with `first_valid_index()` method in order to determine mode value.

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# make a sample data
list_of_rows = [
  {'start_station': 1, 'end_station': 1},
  {'start_station': None, 'end_station': 1},
  {'start_station': 1, 'end_station': 2},
  {'start_station': 1, 'end_station': 3},
  {'start_station': 2, 'end_station': None},
  {'start_station': 2, 'end_station': 3},
  {'start_station': 2, 'end_station': 3},
]

# make a pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)

# define a function
def fill_NaNs_in_end_station(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['end_station']):
        start_station = row['start_station']
        return df[df['start_station']==start_station].end_station.value_counts().first_valid_index()
    return row['end_station']

# apply function to dataframe
df['end_station'] = df.apply(lambda row: fill_NaNs_in_end_station(row), axis=1)
```