# How to replace NAs in R which get mode from a group

Tags: r, replace, nan, group

For example I have some data

| x | y | Owner | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | A | NA |
| 2 | 2 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | A | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | B | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | C | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | C | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | C | NA |
| 3 | 3 | D | NA |

I want to replace the Nans with the most common/mode when you group by (x,y,Owner)  to get

| x | y | Owner | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | A | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | A | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | B | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | C | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | C | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | C | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | D | NA |

I tried this but I think its replacing everything when I only want to replace the Nas
new_data <- my_data %>% group_by('Owner', 'x', 'y') %>%
mutate(H=mean(H, na.rm=TRUE))

I've seen this: but it doesn't workhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741879/can-i-replace-nans-with-the-mode-of-a-column-in-a-grouped-data-frame

new_data <- my_data %>% group_by('Owner', 'x', 'y') %>%
mutate(H=mean(H, na.rm=TRUE)

But this replaces all the values of H with the mean.
Also sometimes there will be no rows which match ie the group will only have 1 row and that has an Na (or maybe that its more than one but they just have NAs), is there a way to just keep the NA?

(I want it to find all the rows which match theOwner, x and y of the row with the NA and take the mode of their H values)

Comment: I want it to find all the rows which match theOwner, x and y of the row with the NA and take the mode of their H values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Mode` function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode/8189441#8189441) and currently included in the `gtools` package

```
df %>%
   group_by(Owner, x, y) %>%
   mutate(H = replace_na(H, gtools::stat_mode(H, ties = 'first')))

# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   Owner, x, y [6]
      x     y Owner     H
  <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1     1     2 A         1
2     2     5 A         4
3     2     2 A         5
4     2     5 A         4
5     2     5 B         4
6     2     5 C         3
7     3     3 C         6
8     3     3 C         6
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to change any of the values

Comment: @MS what do you mean it does not change? Look at the example above. The values changed. Perhaps you need to save into a nev variable ie `df1 <- df %>%....` then look at `df1`

Comment: Does this work if there are rows which are unique and have an NA for H? ie keeping them NA?   Sorry what I mean when the values don't change was for my large csv

Comment: Could it be that I have other columns?

Comment: @MS other columns have nothing to do with the function. Check the code again. Try it on your example. Then try it on you whole dataset. Check the output and not the data itself

Comment: This didn't work  x <- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y <- c(2,5,2,5,5,5,3,3,3)
Owner <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'C', 'C', 'C' , 'D')
H <- c(1, NA, 5,4,4,3,6,NA,NA)

super_sleepers <- data.frame(x, y, Owner, H)

super_sleepers %>% group_by(Owner, x, y) %>%
   mutate(H = replace_na(H, gtools::stat_mode(H, ties = 'first')))

Comment: Ah it doesn't work for me as I have rows where they are unique (ie I can't get a mode) and I want to keep NA. The smaller example I tried just above didn't work until I removed the last row

Comment: @MS that does not make sense. The mode of 1 number is just 1 number. Just as the mean, median, max, min etc of 1 number is just that number. So you cannot expect it to be NA. I am sorry I do no understand what you want and what you mean. The code provided here works as intended. Perharps you will have to change the parameters of your question. It seems you are interested in more than just replacing the NA by the mode but rather to retain the NA's that are in a  group of one observation

Comment: Sorry yes your code works except for the edge case when there is a row with NA for the H, and there are no other rows with the same unique (x,y,owner)

Comment: @MS still the code I have works. Try it out on your new data